# datagridview not updating to bound datasource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, databound

I am trying to get the datagridview to update when I update the datasource and I'm having no luck whatsoever.

Here is my binding:

```
Private _dgbNews As SortableBindingList(Of SalesMessageRecord)

Private Sub SalesMessageScreen_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  '_dgbNews.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
  _dgbNews = AllNews()
  BindingSource1.DataSource = AllNews()
  DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
  MassageDemRows()
End Sub
```

this is `AllNews()`:

```
Public Function AllNews() As SortableBindingList(Of SalesMessageRecord)

  Dim sm = New SortableBindingList(Of SalesMessageRecord)
  Dim allnewsitems = News.GetAllNewsItems(Configuration.CompanyID).ToList()

  For Each allnewz As News In allnewsitems
    Dim smr = New SalesMessageRecord
    smr.Body = allnewz.NewsBody
    smr.CorporationId = CType(allnewz.CorporationId, Guid)
    smr.Expiration = allnewz.Expiration
    smr.IsActive = allnewz.IsActive
    smr.NewsId = allnewz.NewsId
    smr.Title = allnewz.NewsTitle
    smr.SortOrder = allnewz.OrderNumber
    smr.TokenId = allnewz.TokenId
    smr.IsNew = False
    sm.Add(smr)
  Next

  Return sm

End Function
```

And this is where I'm trying to update it:

```
Private Sub button_Save_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button_Save.Click
  If _currentRow < 0 Then
    Return
  End If

  _dgbNews(_currentRow).Expiration = datetimepicker_ExpirationDate.Value
  _dgbNews(_currentRow).SortOrder = CInt(numericupdown_SortNumber.Value)
  _dgbNews(_currentRow).IsActive = checkbox_Active.Checked
  _dgbNews(_currentRow).Body = richtextbox_Body.Text
  _dgbNews(_currentRow).Title = textbox_Title.Text

  DataGridView1.Refresh()

  News.UpdateNewsRecord(_dgbNews(_currentRow).NewsId,
                        _dgbNews(_currentRow).Expiration,
                        _dgbNews(_currentRow).SortOrder,
                        _dgbNews(_currentRow).IsActive,
                        _dgbNews(_currentRow).Body,
                        _dgbNews(_currentRow).Title)
End Sub
```

The database is updating without issue but the datagridview won't update.

Comment: Why do you refresh the datagrid before executing News.UpdateNewsRecord ?  Try:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580053/binding-data-to-datagridview-in-vb-net?rq=1

Comment: News.UpdateNewsRecord is what updates my database. It should not affect the datagridview. Also, I've changed it to not use the BindingSource but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'll take a crack at this. Bindingsources are really useful when used together with a DGV. However, they tend to be aweful in the way that they give no information what so ever why they aren't working.

First of I would say that your binding source has the wrong Datasource.

```
_dgbNews = AllNews()
BindingSource1.DataSource = AllNews()
DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

As you can se you have AllNews() as Datasource. But you add stuff to _dgbNews and expect Allnews() to change. Protip, it doesn't. If you were to set the DataSource to this:

```
BindingSource1.DataSource = _dgbNews
```

Then atleast you should expect some change when the list is updated. Now this is what you actually do miss. In button save click you add an item to  the list, this is now fine if you done the above. But wait, the datasource changed and nothing happened. This is because you don't tell the datagridview to change. Make the Bindingsource tell everything it's connected to to update. With this:

```
BindingSource1.ResetBindings(True)
```

This is better than DGV.Refresh (which might work now) since your bindingsource could be attached to other things (I know it isn't, but for future reference).

Try this and well see if it will go better.

Answer (score 0):

Had similiar issue with DataGridView not displaying any data from my datasource, figured out that my binding class properties were regular int or string instead of being declared with get set.

changed from

int RedeemID;

to

public int RedeemID { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

(AFTER EXECUTING THE UPDATE COMMAND FROM THE DATA ADAPTER)

```
GRIDVIEW_NAME.DATABIND()
```

Answer (score 0):

Me.TableAdapter1.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Table1)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to explain how your code solves the question.